# How to upload file to FTP server in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

My Code is to Upload file to FTP

```
 $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, 4480);
 $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
 $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_BINARY);
```

Its giving this error

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_nb_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: Operation now in progress (115) in /home/nanobi/PHP/ftp.php on line 51
PHP Warning:  ftp_nb_put(): Type set to I in /home/nanobi/PHP/ftp.php
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: did you check folder permission?

Comment: ya i'm able to upload through JAVA program from same machine

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be experiencing [Bug #55651: Option to force PHP to ignore the PASV address returned](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55651). There's an issue when an FTP server behind a NAT device returns its local address in response to the `PASV` command. There's been a patch submitted for this issue years ago, but it hasn't made it into the source yet.

If your FTP server is behind a NAT device, try another FTP client for PHP and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks Roy,  Can i had tha patch to my machine and what is the steps.

Comment: Is it your FTP server? The easiest way to fix this might just be to configure the server not to send its IP when you run the `PASV` command.